# Why doesn't ANTLR recognise this rule the way I expect?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr3

I'm using ANTLR to replace an existing (small) parser I currently have.  Here is a snippet of the file I am trying to parse:

```
Lurker    915236167 10  2 Bk  cc    b     b         1000   70  200 Jc Qs
Lurker    915236237 10  1 Bc  kf    -     -         1130   10    0 
Lurker    915236302 10 10 c   c     rc    b         1120  110  305 6d Kd
Lurker    915236381 10  9 c   f     -     -         1315   20    0 
Lurker    915236425 10  8 cc  f     -     -         1295   30    0
```

Here is Shared.g:

```
lexer grammar Shared;


NICK
    : LETTER (LETTER | NUMBER | SPECIAL)*
    ;

fragment
LETTER 
    : 'A'..'Z'
    | 'a'..'z'
    | '_'
    ;

NUMBER
    : ('0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9')+
    ;

fragment
SPECIAL
    : ('-'|'^'|'{'|'}'|'|'|'['|']'|'`'|'\\')
    ;

WS  
    :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        )+
    ;
```

And Pdb.g:

```
grammar Pdb;
import Shared;

@header{
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Connection;
}


@members{
    private Connection conn;

    private StringBuilder currentExpr = new StringBuilder(500);

    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>(10);

    public void setConn(Connection conn){
        this.conn = conn;
    }
}

pdb
    : line+
    ;

line
    @after{
        currentExpr.append("execute player_handplan(");
        currentExpr.append($nick.text);
        currentExpr.append(", to_timestamp(");
        currentExpr.append(Integer.parseInt($timestamp.text));
        currentExpr.append("), ");
        currentExpr.append(Integer.parseInt($n_players.text));
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append(Integer.parseInt($position.text));
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append($action_p.text);
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append($action_f.text);
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append($action_t.text);
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append($action_r.text);
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append(Integer.parseInt($bankroll.text));
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append(Integer.parseInt($total_action.text));
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append(Integer.parseInt($amount_won.text));
        currentExpr.append(", ");
        currentExpr.append("CARDS");
        currentExpr.append(");");
        System.out.println(currentExpr.toString());
        currentExpr = new StringBuilder(500);
    }
    : nick=NICK WS
      timestamp=NUMBER WS
      n_players=NUMBER WS
      position=NUMBER WS 
      action_p=action WS
      action_f=action WS
      action_t=action WS
      action_r=action WS
      bankroll=NUMBER WS
      total_action=NUMBER WS
      amount_won=NUMBER WS
      (NICK WS NICK WS)? // ignore this
     ;

action
    : '-'
    | ('B'|'f'|'k'|'b'|'c'|'r'|'A'|'Q'|'K')+
    ;
```

My problem is, when I run the parser, I get the following error:

```
cal@lambda:~/src/DecisionTrees/grammar/output$ cat example | java Test 
line 1:26 no viable alternative at input 'Bk'
line 1:30 no viable alternative at input 'cc'
execute player_handplan(Lurker, to_timestamp(915236167), 10, 2, null, null, b, b, 1000, 70, 200, CARDS);
```

Why won't my grammar accept "Bk", even though it will accept "b"?  I feel like there is something obvious I am overlooking.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change input and find what other alternatives the resultant parser will not accept.

Comment: It seems to reject all strings that are more than one character at that point.  "c" works, "cc" does not, etc

Comment: Why is `action` defined in the parser and not the lexer?

Comment: Just curious, but why are you using ANTLR for this? That seems like shooting flies with a cannon.  This is a simple line and field-oriented parsing task that doesn't really need an LR parser.

Comment: @Jim, although the name suggest otherwise, ANTLR is no LR parser generator (but LL). LR in ANTLR stands for "Language Recognition".

Comment: ... but I agree with @Jim here: this may be a bit overkill: the format seems to be fairly straight forward to parse "by hand".

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `{$channel=HIDDEN}` in rule WS and leave them out of the line rule.

That way at least you won't get in trouble for putting one too many `WS` by accident.

And if action can only have 2 chars max maybe trying this will help:

```
action
    : '-'
    | ('B'|'f'|'k'|'b'|'c'|'r'|'A'|'Q'|'K')('B'|'f'|'k'|'b'|'c'|'r'|'A'|'Q'|'K')?
    ;
```